# Packets out of order. Got: 80 Expected: 0 node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, server

Here is my (very simple) code :

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(infosDB);
connection.connect()
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM action`, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

The `action` table is not empty... I think my database is ok.

This code works very well for me on localhost.
However, I bought A2 Hosting to launch node.js (v6.10.3 on localhost and server) project and I get that error when I try to launch this simple code.

```
{ Error: Packets out of order. Got: 80 Expected: 0
    at Parser.write (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:42:19)
    at Protocol.write (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at update_infos_all_users (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/app.js:570:9)
    at Job.job (/home/westudec/public_html/myapp/app.js:1566:3)
    at Job.invoke (/home/westudec/public_html/myapp/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:172:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/hello1234/public_html/myapp/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:542:11)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER', fatal: true }
```

The weird thing is that all work good on my computer.
Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please did you find a solution to this?